# How to label an array property to an API call?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have an array of objects which are of the following structure :

```
const array = [{id: 1, loc: "A"}, {id: 2, loc: "B"}, {id: 3, loc: "C"}];
```

Now I need to use id property in the array as a label to each api call, so that I can differentiate which API call to which item in the array.

like :

```
export function *callSaga(action: item.Action){
const result = yield all([
                array.map(ar => {
                   return {
                        ar.id :  call(apiCall, action.metadata.client, moveReq)
                   };
                })
            ]);
}
```

when I hove over the error at ar.id it says ',' expected  . How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you elaborate "error"?

Comment: when I hover over the error  I get : ' , ' expected

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the value of the variable/object as a key you need to put it in `[]`:

`[ar.id]:  call(apiCall, action.metadata.client, moveReq)`

If you want to use `ar.id` as a key you need to add quotes around it:

`"ar.id":  call(apiCall, action.metadata.client, moveReq)`